# ¿Por qué este "case" no coincide con ninguna opción?

Tags: bash, condiciones, shell-script

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código, al cual le estoy tratando de pasar distintos flags, y que según sea el caso, ejecute una función.

El problema es que si le paso cualquiera de estos, por ejemplo `./script.sh -v`, ejecuta siempre la opción por defecto `defaultMenu`. Al parecer `case` no coincide ningún termino.

```
case $1 in
    [-h,--help]) usage;;
    [-v,--version]) version;;
    [-i,--install]) instala;;
    [-it,--installTmux,-ut,--updateTmux]) tmuxCfg && exit 0;;
    [-ir,--installTern,-ur,--updateTern]) ternCfg && exit 0;;
    [-iz,--installZsh,-uz,--updateZsh]) zshCfg && exit 0;;
    [-in,--installNvim,-un,--updateNvim]) nvimCfg && exit 0;;
    [-um,--updateMedioComplaceme]) medioComplaceme;;
    [-ua,--updateAll]) everyFile;;
    *) defaultMenu;;
esac
```

¿Alguien ve por qué no funciona?

Algo interesante, es que al hacer un `echo $1` me arroja como resultado el `-v`.

PD: ¿Alguien conoce alguna herramienta de debugging para los scripts de bash?

Comment: Probá con `case "$1" in`.

Comment: @MarioL Nope, no funciona

Comment: Fijate acá: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169912 también, a lo mejor te sirve

Comment: Tampoco, si quieres puedes verlo completo aquí: https://gitlab.com/nintF1link/dotfiles/blob/master/medio_complaceme.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo probé de esta forma y funciona:

```
...
case "$1" in
    -h | --help) usage;;
    -v | --version) version;;
    -i | --install) instala;;
    -it | --installTmux | -ut |--updateTmux) tmuxCfg && exit 0;;
    -ir | --installTern | -ur |--updateTern) ternCfg && exit 0;;
    -iz | --installZsh | -uz |--updateZsh) zshCfg && exit 0;;
    -in | --installNvim | -un |--updateNvim) nvimCfg && exit 0;;
    -um | --updateMedioComplaceme) medioComplaceme;;
    -ua | --updateAll) everyFile;;
    *) defaultMenu;;
esac
...
```

Tienes que sacar los `[` `]`, ya que estos sólo indican los inicios y finales de cada expresión.

Comment: Sería bueno indicar qué cambiaste, para que sea de utilildad en el futuro

Answer (score 3):

Lo que ocurre es que es errónea la forma de usar patrones múltiples en un `case`, si revisas las [documentación de bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b):

> *case*
>
> The syntax of the case command is:
>
> *case word in [ [(] pattern [| pattern]…) command-list ;;]… esac:*
>
> case will selectively execute the command-list corresponding to the
>   first pattern that matches word. If the nocasematch shell option (see
>   the description of shopt in The Shopt Builtin) is enabled, the match
>   is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters. **The
>   ‘|’ is used to separate multiple patterns**, and the ‘)’ operator
>   terminates a pattern list. A list of patterns and an associated
>   command-list is known as a clause.

**Nota**: en la definición los `[` y `]` no son literales, solo indican los comienzos y finales de cada construcción.

Es decir, que se debe usar `|` para separar los patrones. Por tanto, en lugar de:

```
[-v,--version]) version;;
```

debes usar:

```
-v | --version) version;;
```

Tu ejemplo, con los cambios quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
case "$1" in
    -h | --help) usage;;
    -v | --version) version;;
    -i | --install) instala;;
    -it | --installTmux | -ut |--updateTmux) tmuxCfg && exit 0;;
    -ir | --installTern | -ur |--updateTern) ternCfg && exit 0;;
    -iz | --installZsh | -uz |--updateZsh) zshCfg && exit 0;;
    -in | --installNvim | -un |--updateNvim) nvimCfg && exit 0;;
    -um | --updateMedioComplaceme) medioComplaceme;;
    -ua | --updateAll) everyFile;;
    *) defaultMenu;;
esac
```

Comment: Como nota adicional, los corchetes suelen usarse para representar argumentos o partes de construcciones que son opcionales (es decir, pueden ser omitidos). No tengo idea de dónde proviene esta convención, pero asumo que se popularizó gracias a `man` (_"any or all arguments within `[ ]` are optional"_). Incluso POSIX define esta sintaxis (_Utility Argument Syntax_) en su capítulo [_12. Utility Conventions_](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01) (_"Arguments or option-arguments enclosed in the `[` and `]` notation are optional and can be omitted"_).

Comment: Como curiosidad, si nos atenemos a dicha sintaxis, el comando `case word in esac` (sin patrones) debería ser válido pese a no tener mucho sentido (es como si `if` careciera de `then`) e incluso no marca error en `bash`, `dash` y `zsh`.

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, en bash los corchetes representan lo mismo que el comando test, para los condicionales de if. Eso explicaria por que ninguna opcion seria correcta: primero hace el test con la condicion (la cual no tiene sentido por cierto), devuelve false, y por tanto no entraria en ninguna condicion (a excepcion de *). Es una idea para explicar este "fenomeno"  :o)

Comment: @nxnev, buen dato, hace un poco de ruido que se usen los corchetes en la descripción, cuando los corchetes también tienen un sentido en bash.